# Acomodar los items por mes en un recycleView

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion y en un RecycleView estoy metiendo datos y quiero acomodarlos por mes, el punto es que de arriba hacia abajo lo divide bien pero al hacer el scroll de abajo hacia arriba se desplazan los meses.

```
            if(meses.equals("")){
            meses=asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p).getDatetime(),4);
            game.mes.setText(asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p).getDatetime(),4));
        }else {
            if(meses.equals(asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p).getDatetime(),4))){
                game.mes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                if(meses != asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p).getDatetime(),4)){
                    meses=asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p).getDatetime(),4);
                    game.mes.setText(asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p).getDatetime(),4));
                    game.mes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        }
```

Asi queda scroll de arriba hacia abajo:
[image: img Scroll de arriba hacia abajo]

Y asi queda cuando vas de abajo hacia arriba:
[image: img Scroll de abajo hacia arriba]

Estoy aprendiendo a usar recycleview pero me he topado con este problema.

Comment: en el adapter tienes los métodos getItemId y getItemViewType?

Comment: Si, ambos métodos estan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi de esta manera:

```
        if(pos1 <= p){

        if(meses.equals(mescomparacion)){
            game.mes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{

            game.mes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            meses = mescomparacion;

            if(p != 0){

                if(mescomparacion.equals(asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p-1).getDatetime(),4))){
                    game.mes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
        pos1 = p;
    }

    //Scroll hacia arriba
    if(pos1 > p){

        if(p != 0){
            meses = asignarFecha(adapterList.get(p-1).getDatetime(),4);
        }else{
            game.mes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pos = 1;
        }

        if(meses.equals(mescomparacion) && pos == 0){
            game.mes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            meses = mescomparacion;
        }else{
            game.mes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            meses = mescomparacion;
        }
        pos1 = p;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(TYPE_HEADER, 0); //(TYPE_HEADER vendría a ser el itemViewType de tu vista agrupadora)
```

En donde inicializas tu adapter. Con esto indicas que la vista correspondiente a tu header agrupador no se recicle durante el scroll. Aunque debes considerar que esto tiene un impacto importante en el performance de tu aplicación.

Esto también puede funcionar:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

en tu viewholder.

Comment: Intente implementar la primera forma y obtuve el mismo resultado, y creo que al implementar la segunda le quito todo el sentido al uso de recycleview